# Libdvdread4 not available from videolan?

Tags: 14.04, dvd

Trying to play get DVD functionality working on my fresh 14.04 install. I found and installed ubuntu-restricted-extras, but then when I try to move to the next step, I get this:

```
drake@drake-GA-MA78GM-US2H:~$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
[sudo] password for drake: 
--2014-12-20 09:50:05--  http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable//Packages
Resolving download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)... 195.154.236.203, fe80::be30:5bff:fed0:40f9
Connecting to download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)|195.154.236.203|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: unspecified
ERROR: Redirection (301) without location.
Dynamic fetch failed; Falling back to static fetch
--2014-12-20 09:50:05--  http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
Resolving download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)... 195.154.236.203, fe80::be30:5bff:fed0:40f9
Connecting to download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)|195.154.236.203|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-12-20 09:50:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I've tried looking it up on my own, but all I get is talking about how the packages got moved from medibuntu to videolan. Which is fine, but it's apparently not on videolan anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an hardware failure on videoLAN's side.

Hopefully it'll be fixed in the next few days.

See this thread https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=123251 for details and updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you poke around a bit you'll see that the web site has

http://download.videolan.org/libdvdcss/1.3.0/

I'm not sure what to do with that.